# This code from learnpython.org returns an error

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to Python, but I wasn't expecting to have trouble with string formatting. I tried following the instructions from the exercise at the bottom of [this webpage](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting), and that returned an error, so eventually I clicked on the solution, copied that in, and it also produced an error.

```
data = ("John", "Doe", 53.44)
format_string = "Hello %s %s. Your current balance is $%s."

print(format_string % data)
```

And it returned this in Console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\tokenize.py", line 390, in find_cookie
    line_string = line.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 54: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 119, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 37, in debug
    run(address, filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_local.py", line 64, in run_file
    run(argv, addr, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_local.py", line 125, in _run
    _pydevd.main()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1752, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1099, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1106, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 14, in execfile
    stream = tokenize.open(file)  # @UndefinedVariable
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\tokenize.py", line 454, in open
    encoding, lines = detect_encoding(buffer.readline)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\tokenize.py", line 441, in detect_encoding
    encoding = find_cookie(second)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\tokenize.py", line 395, in find_cookie
    raise SyntaxError(msg)
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for 'C:\\Users\\Leo\\source\\repos\\Hello World\\Hello World\\Hello_World.py'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Honestly, I'm not sure what to make of this error message. I'm using Python 3 in Visual Studio 2017. I'm wondering if the code is wrong or if there's something wrong with my set-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I've figured out what went wrong. I had commented code above the code I was trying to run, and that seemed to stop it from working properly. I removed the code and it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code has no errors. I ran it in the terminal and it works. Looks like something is wrong with your setup

Comment: Any idea what could conceivably be wrong with the set-up, or how I might go about correcting the set-up?

Comment: Ah, never mind, I've worked out why. I had commented code above the code I was trying to run, and assumed that would be okay. Turns out it's not. When I removed the commented code, the error disappeared.